# What are considered landmark ideas on happiness among modern philosophers?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, happiness

Yes, there was Aristotle's understanding of it as an objective, and Epicurus providing a recipe. David Hume concurred, "The great end of all human industry is the attainment of happiness. For this were arts invented, sciences cultivated, laws ordained, and societies modeled, by the most profound wisdom of patriots and legislators." There are Kierkegaard's quotes, like "People settle for a level of despair they can tolerate and call it happiness." seemingly dismissing the idea. And then there is the idea of emptiness in Buddhism.

But is 'happiness' an object of thought in modern philosophy, loosely understood?

Jorge Luis Borges said, "He cometido el peor pecado que uno puede cometer: No ser feliz." (Translation: *I have committed the worst sin that one can commit: Not being happy.*) Yet, he was not a philosopher. Wittgenstein was, and through his dark clouds he summarized at the end: “Tell them I've had a wonderful life.” Borges, I would humbly venture, probably did too - at least in the way of the happiness he generated for his readers.

Comment: 'happiness' can have different meanings to different people. What is happiness to you is not necessarily happiness to me. There are even people whose definition of happiness is inflicting pain and suffering on others, and people who are not happy if they themselves are not suffering. Everyone wants happiness but what 'happiness' 'is' is defined individually.

Comment: Wittgenstein also said: " I don't know why we are here, but I'm pretty sure that it is not in order to enjoy ourselves." When he said 'a wonderful life', he did not mean it conventionally. Discussed here: "How did Hume remain 'jovial', 'merry' and 'unperturbed' despite philosophy's difficulty?" https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/36260/how-did-hume-remain-jovial-merry-and-unperturbed-despite-philosophys-dif/81730#81730 W. also said: "The only life that is happy is the life that can renounce the amenities of the world. To it the amenities of the world are so many graces of fate."

Comment: In modern philosophy, the greatest shift in the conception of "happiness" would probably be Bentham, Mill, and the utilitarians, whose views retain a global hegemony through liberal political-economy. Prescriptions for personal happiness were largely overtaken since Kant by recognition of "freedom" as an ideal. Of course, there may be any number of views among individual philosophers, and it is naturally a field in which, I suspect, Socratic self-knowledge is still equated with happiness.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow that the current Dalai Lama of Tibetan Buddhism is a modern philosopher (and he has certainly updated a lot of traditional philosophy for the modern, scientific ear), he has expounded a great deal on the subject, including publishing a book titled *The Art of Happiness*. This recasting of the Buddhist agenda is not as trite a device as it might seem; his argument is that if you want long-term happiness, more than just a temporary buzz, then you have to seek within, to follow the Buddhist path to enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Happiness as expressed as *Eudaimonia* or *Ataraxia* in ancient western philosophy was extensively discussed by Aristotle and Pyrrho. Cynics and Stoics (primarily influenced by cynics such as Crates of Thebes) emphasized *virtue* as their version of happiness and morality consistently syncretized. For contemorary philosophers discussing similar topic is referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_happiness):

> Władysław Tatarkiewicz
> Władysław Tatarkiewicz (1886–1980) was a Polish philosopher, historian of philosophy, historian of art, esthetician, and ethicist. For Tatarkiewicz, happiness is a fundamental ethical category.

> Viktor Frankl
> Viktor Frankl (1905–1997) was an Austrian neurologist, psychiatrist, Holocaust survivor and founder of logotherapy. His philosophy revolved around the emphasis on meaning, the value of suffering, and responsibility to something greater than the self; only if one encounters those questions can one be happy.

> Robert Nozick (1938–2002) was an American philosopher and professor at Harvard University. He is best known for his political philosophy, but he proposed two thought experiments directly tied to issues on Philosophy of Happiness. In his 1974 book, Anarchy, State, Utopia, he proposed a thought experiment where one is given the option to enter a machine that would give the maximum amount of unending hedonistic pleasure for the entirety of one's life. The machine described in his thought experiment is often described as the "Experience Machine." The machine works by giving the participant connected to it the sensation of any experience they desired and is said to produce sensations that are indistinguishable from real life experiences.

> Nozick outlined the "utility monster" thought experiment as an attempted criticism to utilitarianism. Utilitarian ethics provides guidance for acting morally, but also to maximizing happiness. The utility monster is a hypothetical being that generates extreme amount of theoretical pleasure units compared to the average person. Consider a situation such as the utility monster receiving fifty units of pleasure from eating a cake versus forty other people receiving only one unit of pleasure per cake eaten. Although each individual receives the same treatment or good, the utility monster somehow generates more than all the other people combined. Given many utilitarian commitments to maximizing utility related to pleasure, the thought experiment is meant to force utilitarians to commit themselves to feeding the utility monster instead of a mass of other people, despite our general intuitions insisting otherwise. The criticism essentially comes in the form of a *reductio ad absurdum* criticism by showing that utilitarians adopt a view that is absurd to our moral intuitions, specifically that we should consider the utility monster with much more regard than a number of other people.

> Sonja Lyubomirsky asserted in her 2007 book, The How of Happiness, that happiness is 50 percent genetically determined (based on twin studies), 10 percent circumstantial, and 40 percent subject to self-control.

> Not all cultures seek to maximise happiness, and some cultures are averse to happiness. Also June Gruber suggests that seeking happiness can have negative effects, such as failed over-high expectations, and instead advocates a more open stance to all emotions. Other research has analysed possible trade-offs between happiness and meaning in life.